# PgSQL - Error while executing a select

Tags: postgresql, select

I am trying to write a simple select query in PgSQL but I keep getting an error. I am not sure what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
select residuals, residuals/stddev_pop(residuals)
from mySchema.results;
```

This gives an error

```
ERROR:  column "results.residuals" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Residuals is a numeric value (continuous variable)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`stddev_pop`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-STATISTICS-TABLE) is an *aggregate function*. That means that it takes a set of rows as its input. Your query mentions two values in the SELECT clause:

1. `residuals`, this is a value from a single row.
2. `stddev_pop(residuals)`, this is an aggregate value and represents multiple rows.

You're not telling PostgreSQL how it should choose the singular `residuals` value to go with the aggregate standard deviation and so PostgreSQL says that `residuals`

> must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish so I can't tell you how to fix your query. A naive suggestion would be:

```
select residuals, residuals/stddev_pop(residuals)
from mySchema.results
group by residuals
```

but that would leave you computing the standard deviation of groups of identical values and that doesn't seem terribly productive (especially when you're going to use the standard deviation as a divisor).

Perhaps you need to revisit the formula you're trying to compute as well as fixing your SQL.

If you want to compute the standard deviation separately and then divide each `residuals` by that then you'd want something like this:

```
select residuals,
       residuals/(select stddev_pop(residuals) from mySchema.results)
from mySchema.results
```

Comment: group by residuals will remove the sql error but will give me incorrect values. As residual is a continuous variable I dont think I can use it in a group by

Comment: As I said, `group by residuals` doesn't make sense in the statistics since `stddev_pop(residuals)` would be zero in that case. Maybe you want to compute `residuals/stddev` as in my updated answer.